# Cannot use different slug names for the same dynamic path, but different slug

Tags: next.js

When I ran `npm run dev`, I got this error:

```
Error: You cannot use different slug names for the same dynamic path ('uid' !== 'subtopic').
```

This is my folder structure. Why did I get this error?

[image]

Comment: [subtopic] and [uid] is at next point of view is the same. That's why it throws error like that. Now if you want to keep [uid].js put it inside the [subtopic] folder and renamed it to index.js